# Citing articles in languages different from that of the journal

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, languages, best-practices

Journals in languages other than the current *lingua franca* of science will sometimes publish articles in a language other than their main one. For example, “Normierte Ringe” by Israel Gelfand (on Banach algebras) [was published](http://mi.mathnet.ru/sm6046) in the Russian-language *Математический сборник* [Matematičeskij sbornik], but should probably be still cited in as Т.9 №1 and not B.9 N.9 even if `autocite=other` is in effect; the author name and article title are to be hyphenated as German while the journal name as Russian.

Similarly if less problematically, Feynman’s talk “Quantum theory of gravitation” (on gauge quantization) [was published](https://blogs.umass.edu/grqft/files/2014/11/Feynman-gravitation.pdf) in *Acta Physica Polonica*, which [also accepted](http://przyrbwn.icm.edu.pl/APP/PDF/100/A100Z0_intro2.pdf) papers in French and German.  Most of the articles in [the 2021 issue](https://comptes-rendus.academie-sciences.fr/mathematique/volume/CRMATH_2021__359_7/) of *Comptes rendus. Mathématique* were written in English, but [one by Deligne](https://comptes-rendus.academie-sciences.fr/mathematique/articles/10.5802/crmath.242/) was in French.

How can such a situation be described to BibLaTeX? It only seems to accept a single `langid`/`hyphenation` value for the whole record, and as I understand it the [multiscript work](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/416) is concerned more with making the entry conform to the language of the surrounding document, not including multiple languages inside a single citation. I can of course always decorate the database entries with `\foreignlanguage`, but without additional work that will ruin sorting.